# Get difference of two dates through mysql

Tags: mysql, datediff

I'm not being able to find the exact answer for **6** hours now...!!

i want to display Birthdays in an order in which, **upcoming birthday is displayed first.**

```
$today_date = date('Y-m-d');

$s = "select * from BDays order by TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d') , $today_date)";
```

The column containing the dates is labeled as "date" in the table labeled as "BDays".

In the query, i'm trying to subtract the **birth-date** from **Today's date** to get upcoming birthday.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not just put `ORDER BY date_column_name` ?

Comment: It will only sort all the dates... But will not tell the upcoming birthday...

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare just the month and day for each of the date/times with the current month date.  There is a function EXTRACT, where you can do this.  Something like this:

```
$s = "select * from BDays
      order by EXTRACT(MONTH_DAY, date) - EXTRACT(MONTH_DAY, $today_date)";
```

This will return all birthdays, even those that have passed.  To only have upcoming birthdays, try:

```
$s = "select * from BDays
       where (EXTRACT(MONTH_DAY, date) - EXTRACT(MONTH_DAY, $today_date)) > 0
       order by EXTRACT(MONTH_DAY, date) - EXTRACT(MONTH_DAY, $today_date)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    name,
    birthday,
    birthday + INTERVAL(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(birthday)) + 0 YEAR AS currbirthday,
    birthday + INTERVAL(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(birthday)) + 1 YEAR AS nextbirthday
FROM birthdays
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN currbirthday >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN currbirthday
    ELSE nextbirthday
END
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a5c0/1

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
create table BDays (`date` date);
insert into BDays values ('1993-04-01'), ('2015-10-26'), ('1995-08-10'), ('1995-06-05'), ('1994-04-04');

select * from BDays
order by
case 
when `date` > current_date then `date`
else cast(concat(year(`date`)+1, right(`date`, 6)) as date)
end
```

Result:

```
|                      date |
|---------------------------|
|   April, 01 1993 00:00:00 |
|   April, 04 1994 00:00:00 |
|    June, 05 1995 00:00:00 |
|  August, 10 1995 00:00:00 |
| October, 26 2015 00:00:00 |
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d60e2/2

We are ordering by date here. If the birth date is yet to arrive, use that date. Otherwise take the next year and combine it with month and day. Then sort it.

In your dates appear as DD-MM-YYYY, you can use `cast( concat(left(date, 6), year(date)+1) as date)` or something on those lines.

EDIT:

```
-- added 1994-11-27 to the table
create table BDays (`date` date);
insert into BDays values ('1993-04-01'), ('2015-10-26'), ('1995-08-10'), ('1995-06-05'), ('1994-04-04'), ('1994-11-27');

-- updated query
select * from BDays
order by
case 
when `date` > current_date then `date`
else cast(concat(year(current_date)+1, right(`date`, 6)) as date)
end
```

Result:

```
|                       date |
|----------------------------|
|    April, 01 1993 00:00:00 |
|    April, 04 1994 00:00:00 |
|     June, 05 1995 00:00:00 |
|   August, 10 1995 00:00:00 |
|  October, 26 2015 00:00:00 |
| November, 27 1994 00:00:00 |
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f448/13

Comment: Added an EDIT. Is that the result you were looking for?

Comment: @user46329 did this answer help you?